# How can I realize android.app.Service in MVP?

Tags: android, android-service, mvp

I create Firebase service and I want save data to room when I get Notification. I use MVP and I do not understand how can I use MVP in `android.app.Service`

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


    @Inject
    EventPresenter presenter;

    public NfpFirebaseMessagingService() {
        presenter = UserApplication.me().getAppComponent().getEventPresenter();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        presenter.saveEvent(data);
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData());
    }
```

but my presenter has view and `FirebaseMessagingService` - is not view. How can I realize MVP in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can tread `Service` as your `View`. It can implement an interface which do not need to be called View, but you can rename it to Service.

You can just simply prepare interface:

```
interface ServiceI {
  void emitEvent();
}
```

than your service needs to implement this interface

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService implements ServiceI {
...
}
```

and you can pass this object to the presenter.